# Create Unique Arrays Based on Reference Subfolders

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to automate creating a unique array for each reference subfolder (blue folder) that contains the contents of the subfolder. I'd like to do this by way of a for loop. The process would be to read the reference folder, then create an array with a unique name for each subfolder and add the contents of the subfolder to its respective array. Then I can access the contents of the subfolder by calling it's array.

I can almost do it with the code provided except that it does not create unique arrays for each subfolder.

```
MainFolder
   SubFolder1
      SF1_Content1
      SF1_Content2
   SubFolder2
      SF2_Content1
      SF2_Content2
   SubFolder3
      SF3_Content1
      SF3_Content2



//viewDidLoad

dataDir = string path to MainFolder

for (int i = 0; i <= [mainFolderArray count] -1; i++) {

NSString *sectionString = [mainFolderArray objectAtIndex:i];    

NSMutableArray *subFolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"sectionString = %@", sectionString);

NSArray *subTitleArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", dataDir, sectionString] error:nil];

[subFolderArray addObject:subTitleArray];

NSLog(@"Contents of subFolder = %@", subFolderArray);

}
```

returns...

```
 sectionString = SubFolder1
 Contents of subFolder = (
    (
    "SF1_Content1",
    "SF1_Content2"       
  )
 )
 sectionString = SubFolder2
 Contents of subFolder = (
    (
    "SF2_Content1",
    "SF2_Content2"
 )
)
sectionString = fiveArray
Contents of subFolder = (
    (
    "SF3_Content1",
    "SF3_Content2"
 )
)
```

Here, the for loop produces the same subfolder array over and over. I'd like to create a new array each loop of the likes subfolder1, subfolder2 and so on. Please provide suggestions to get the desired intent. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the for loop, declare a NSMutableArray called allFolders, and in each loop, do

```
[allFolders addObject:subFolderArray];
```